# Meaning of "material characteristic"

Tags: word-meaning

From a pharmacological document (production of a drug):

> Critical output attributes: **Material characteristic** representing critical quality attributes (CQA) a and target product profile.

> Non-critical output attributes: **Material characteristic** that represents performance parameters (e.g. cell count, viability, yield) and/or generates process trend and knowledge.

What is the meaning of **material characteristic** here? A characteristic of a material? Very important characteristic? Physical characteristic? (Measurable in some physical way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could mean "characteristics of the material", i.e. the chemicals used in the drugs. Or it could be using "material" in the sense of "relevant", to mean "relevant" or "important" characteristics. Either interpretation makes sense in context, and in practice, the overall meaning is the same either way.